# The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) int, AtomicLong

Tags: java, atomic-long

I have a Map as below -

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong>();
```

This map contains lot of key value pair. Putting the `AtomicLong` as the value was necessary so that is the reason I have put like that in that map.

So now if I am trying to iterate through `ConcurrentHashMap` that I mentioned above, it always give me error on this line-

```
buckets[i] += histogram.get(time);
```

as- `The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) int, AtomicLong`

I am not sure how can I fix this problem? I cannot go back and change the data structure to all `Integer` instead of `Long` and `AtomicLong`.

So I need to find out how to make change in the below code so that it starts working. I was thinking of casting to Integer. But it was also not working.

Below is my code

```
private static void logHistogramInfo() {

    System.out.println("From Main Thread: " + histogram);

    int[] definition = { 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 };
    int[] buckets = new int[definition.length];

    for (Long time : histogram.keySet()) {
        for (int i = definition.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (time >= definition[i]) {
                      //error on the below line
                buckets[i] += histogram.get(time);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < definition.length; i++) {
        String period = "";
        if (i == definition.length - 1) {
            period = "greater than " + definition[i] + "ms";
        } else {
            period = "between " + (definition[i] + 1) + " and " + definition[i + 1] + "ms";
        }
        System.out.println(buckets[i] + " came back " + period);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `histogram.get(time).longValue()`?

Comment: `buckets[i] += histogram.get(time).get();` - you should also declare your buckets as a `long[]` to prevent overflows.

Comment: @assylias What will be the difference between your answer and arne.b answer? Just wondering what can be the possible difference.

Comment: @FarhanJamal I don't think there is one - longValue is inherited from Number whereas get is part of the AtomicXXX api. I just find get clearer in that case. But both should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+=` operator was originally intended for use with the primitive data types (`int`, `long`...). Since these cannot be put in a map, the wrapper classes exists. When you use an `Integer` or `Long` with any arithmetic operator, these are automatically "unboxed" to their corresponding primitive type.

However, there is no primitive type corresponding to any `AtomicXYZ`. You can, however, use any of the methods the `Number` class provides to get its value as a primitive, e.g. `longValue()` or `intValue()`. Note that the value of your atomic long can in principle be larger than the largest `int` (or `Integer`), so you may want to deal with the potential overflow in some way.

[edit] Or you can use the `get()` method as assylias points out (which I was not aware of as I never used the atomic types before), which does the same thing as `longValue()` for `AtomicLong` (and the same thing as `intValue()` for `AtomicInteger`), as can be seen from its implementation.